# query that counts items and who looked at them

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query that counts items and who looked at them.  I don't know if its even possible.  Basically i'm trying to have it look at something decide if it should count it and order it by the person who looked at it.

I've been looking around and all the examples that I've looked at don't show anything like this.  I know with the code below its just counting the same things over and over but every time I try to make it consider the examiner it basically tells me it cant do that.
Edit. As requested here are the 4 tables called in query.

```
CREATE TABLE examiner (
    examinerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName CHAR(10),
    lastName CHAR(15));

CREATE TABLE evidence (
    evidenceID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    faNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    itemNumber VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE,
    evidenceNumber CHAR(10),
    isCDDVD VARCHAR(3),
    make CHAR(20),
    modle CHAR(20),
    identifier CHAR(20),
    typeOfDevice CHAR(20),
    size INT,
    notes VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE storageMedia (
    PRIMARY KEY (belongsTo,subKey),
    belongsTO VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT FK_Evidence_StorageMedia_BelongsTo FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES evidence(itemNumber) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    subKey VARCHAR(5),
    faNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    make CHAR(20),
    modle CHAR(20),
    identifier CHAR(20),
    typeOfStorageDevice CHAR(20),
    evidenceNumber CHAR(10),
    size INT,
    notes VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE faLog (
    faid INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    faNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    caseNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    startDate CHAR(10),
    endDate CHAR(10),
    examinerID INT CONSTRAINT FK_Examiner_FALog_examinerID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES examiner(examinerID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    DetectiveID INT CONSTRAINT FK_Detective_FALog_DetectiveID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES detective(detectiveID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    subjectID INT CONSTRAINT FK_theSubject_FALog_theSubjectID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES theSubject(subjectID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    authorazation CHAR(10),
    faStatus CHAR(15));

    ALTER TABLE evidence ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FAlog_Evidence_FANumber FOREIGN KEY (faNumber) REFERENCES faLog(faNumber) ON DELETE CASCADE;
    ALTER TABLE storageMedia ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FAlog_storageMedia_FANumber FOREIGN KEY (faNumber) REFERENCES faLog(faNumber);
```

The query in question

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.examinerID,
            e.lastName,
            (SELECT COUNT(evidence.typeOfDevice) 
            FROM evidence
            WHERE (evidence.typeOfDevice='HDD' OR evidence.typeOfDevice='SSD'))
            +
            (SELECT COUNT(storageMedia.typeOfStorageDevice) 
            FROM storageMedia
            WHERE (storageMedia.typeOfStorageDevice ='HDD' OR storageMedia.typeOfStorageDevice ='SSD')) AS 'HDD/SSD'
FROM examiner e
    INNER JOIN faLog FA ON FA.examinerID =e.examinerID
    INNER JOIN evidence EVI ON FA.faNumber= EVI.faNumber
    INNER JOIN storageMedia SM ON SM.faNumber =FA.faNumber
--WHERE (EVI.typeOfDevice ='HDD' OR EVI.typeOfDevice ='SSD') OR (SM.typeOfStorageDevice ='HDD'OR SM.typeOfStorageDevice ='SSD')
GROUP BY e.examinerID, e.lastName
```

I'm trying to have it output like this.

```
ID|   Name   |HDD/SSD|

3 |   John   | 15 
8 |   Chris  | 7 
12|   Jake   | 8 
68|   Tyler  | 5
```

...

But with the code above it looks like this.

```
ID|   Name    |HDD/SSD 

3 |   John    | 15

8 |   Chris   | 15

12|   Jake    | 15

68|   Tyler   | 15
```

...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.  Your query references four tables, exactly zero of which are explained.  One can only speculate how "looks at" is expressed in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the subquery. Is the following sql what you want? If not, you have to change the subquery to correlated.

```
SELECT e.examinerID,
                e.lastName,
                 COUNT(DISTINCT EVI.typeOfDevice) 
                +
                COUNT(SM.typeOfStorageDevice) AS 'HDD/SSD'
    FROM examiner e
        INNER JOIN faLog FA ON FA.examinerID =e.examinerID
        INNER JOIN evidence EVI ON FA.faNumber= EVI.faNumber
        INNER JOIN storageMedia SM ON SM.faNumber =FA.faNumber
    WHERE (EVI.typeOfDevice='HDD' OR EVI.typeOfDevice='SSD')
    AND (SM.typeOfStorageDevice ='HDD' OR SM.typeOfStorageDevice ='SSD')
    GROUP BY e.examinerID, e.lastName
```

Comment: Can post some sample data and expected results? I am confused what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You were right i needed a correlated query.  Thank you.  I'm not good at formatting on this website but in words i had two tables in which i was saving types of devices and i wanted to see who handles what devices.  Below i posted the solution I came up with,  Thank you again for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

like previously stated by @peterHe i needed to change it to a correlated query.  This was the way I fixed it 
Thank you @peterHe

`SELECT e.lastName,
        e.firstName,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM evidence EVI 
            INNER JOIN faLog FA ON FA.faNumber=EVI.faNumber
        WHERE EVI.typeOfDevice IN ('HDD','SSD') AND (FA.examinerID=e.examinerID))
        +(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM storageMedia SM 
            INNER JOIN faLog FA ON FA.faNumber=SM.faNumber
        WHERE SM.typeOfStorageDevice IN ('HDD','SSD') AND (FA.examinerID=e.examinerID))
        FROM examiner e`